# Coverage concept and PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgis-raster

I'm trying to understand the implementation of the interplay of raster and vector data in PostGIS. In this article [Coverage Concepts and PostGIS](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiCoveragesAndPostgis#no1) on the PostGIS wiki page the concept of vector and raster coverages is explained (and mentioned [here](http://2010.foss4g.org/presentations/3221.pdf) by Pierre Racine FOSS4G 2010). This article is 11 years old and by going through the PostGIS 3.x documentation I could only rarely find the concept of coverages mentioned anywhere (only [here](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_ValueCount.html) very briefly). I could not find anything related that is more recent. Thus, I am wondering if this concept is still relevant / in use and if it changed - How and to what did the implementation of raster - vector calculation change?
Secondly, I am wondering if I understood the concept correctly that fundamentally all calculations are between coverages whereas the actual vector/raster data is merely the data used in the background. Thus the raster -vector calculations work that seamlessly (?)

Comment: Are you interested in the concept of coverages in general, or just the how coverages are handled in PostGIS

Comment: I am interested in both understanding the concept and understanding how it is then applied in practice

Comment: One place to start would be: [OGC Coverage Implementation Schema](https://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/09-146r6/09-146r6.html)